# ssh connect view options

Tags: linux, ssh

When connecting via ssh like this:

```
ssh example.com
```

I'm assuming at some point all the command line and config options are all combined to form a full command with all the -o options passed to it, something like this:

```
ssh example.com -oForwardX11 no -oPubkeyAuthentication yes ...etc.
```

Is there any way to see what the exact command was?

I used the -vvv flags and they output a lot of info, just not exactly what I need.

Edit: Using OpenSSH 6.2, before the -G flag was introduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not. There is concept of configuration files, where you can set this values and if you don't set up them, the default ones are used. If you are interested in special value, it is quite easy to search for it in manual page `man ssh`) to find the default value and through you configuration files if you redefine it somewhere.

But if you are using recent openssh version (> 6.7 at least), you can use `-G` switch (from manual page):

> -G
>
> Causes **ssh** to print its configuration after evaluating **Host** and **Match** blocks and exit.

So trying:

```
ssh -G example.com
```

should give all information you want.

Comment: Thanks that a great tip, but I'm not using OpenSSH > 6.7. I know about all the options and config files, just want to get an output of the finally selected options. There are multiple config files and I want to see how they are all parsed, so I can write a python script to generate a valid ssh connection string with different parameters. Basically just want to test exactly how the command line options and config options are parsed and combined in different scenarios.

Comment: It is described in manual pages. This config option was added just recently (in last ~year) so if upgrading is not an option for you, I would recommend you to build latest version where you can do this "for free".

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want to build from source, I'm using CentOS 7 and there doesn't seem to be any rpms available, even in the third party repos, epel etc.

Comment: I can build you one we are using in Fedora :) By the way, on current updated CentOS is version 6.6.1p1. It will not make a change in this case, but there are others.

Comment: Thanks for the offer! I just ended up downloading Fedora 23, setting up a virtual machine to do this testing.